# Mobile Browser fires click/tap event twice

Tags: android, jquery, html, ios, jquery-mobile

I've got a mobile web application which when a button is clicked it auto creates a team of players for you. The first time you get no warning as you have no players, however if you have someone already in your team you will receive a warning that they will be removed.

This error only happens when you tap the button quickly, but if you hold the button down for any period of time it only fires once.

Is there a way to have a tap event only fire once? This happens on both iOS and Android (4.3)?

Code below:

```
$(document).on('click tap','.autoTeam',function(e){
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:alink+"assets/scripts/myteam-ajax-0.2",
        data:"page=autoteamCheck&tid="+tid,
        success:function(data2)
        {
            if(data2['totalPlayers'] == 0)
            {
                var c = true;
            }
            else
            {
                c=confirm('Using the auto create will remove all players from your team, are you sure you wish to continue?');
            }
            if(c == true)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type:"POST",
                    url:alink+"assets/scripts/myteam-ajax-0.2",
                    data:"page=autoteam&tid="+tid+"&lid="+lid,
                    success:function(data)
                    {
                        if(data['error'] == 'Y')
                        {
                            alert(data['message']);
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            window.location.reload();
                        }
                    },
                    dataType:"json"
                });
            }
        },
        dataType:"json"
    });
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    e.gesture.preventDefault();
    e.preventDefault(); return false;
});

<input class="button autoTeam" data-role="none" value="Auto Create" type="button"  style="margin-right:20px; font-size:0.8em;"/>
```

Comment: try `vclick` instead.

Comment: is `.autoTeam` dynamically added? if not, then `$('.autoTeam').on('click', function () { });` should work.

Comment: No it's created on screen, does click work on all devices? I thought that was the reason for using click and tap?

Comment: you should use one event i assume, either click, tap, vclick. vclick works on all.

Comment: Safari on iOS does not accept the click event.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was to add `return false;` at the end of the event-handler. Example:

```
$(document).on("click, tap", ".autoTeam", function(event){
    // do thing
    return false; // double event fix
});
```

Comment: Bit of an old question. Adding event.stopImmediatePropagation ended up being the solution i used